# How to make nullable list of int

Tags: c#, .net

I have this string:

```
string alertsId = "1,2,3,4";
```

Then I convert  the string to list of ints:

```
List<int> list = alertsId.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
```

How can I convert the list above to nullable list of ints?

Comment: `List<int> list = null` is possible. what do you mean? Do you want to take into account the case where one of the values in your string could be impossible to convert to an int and then provide null as a value in your list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well a `List<int>` is a reference type and therefor nullable by definition. So I guess you want to create a list of *nullable integers (`List<int?>`)*.

You can simply use `Cast<T>()`:

```
List<int?> nullableList = list.Cast<int?>().ToList();
```

Or to create it directly:

```
List<int?> list = alertsId.Split(',').Select(n => (int?)Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 will cause exception if string is in the wrong format

Answer (score 2):

Define a function:

```
public int? ParseToNullable(string s)
{
    int? result = null;
    int temp = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out temp)) 
    {
         result = temp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
string alertsId = "1,2,3,4";
List<int?> list = alertsId.Split(',').Select(n => ParseToNullable(n)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of Nullable and copy each element of your list into the nullable one, like in the example bellow:

```
            List<Nullable<int>> a = new List<Nullable<int>>();
            List<int> b = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4 };
            foreach (var c in b)
            {
                a.Add((Nullable<int>)c);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Adition to the linq party

```
string alertsId = "1,2,3,4,crap";
List<int?> list = alertsId.Split(',')
           .Select(s => { int i; return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : (int?)null; })
           .ToList();
```

First we split by comma, then we try to parse each element, if its not parseable we return null, and then we convert the array we've been working with to a list.